# Flask-admin how to remove the action for edit and delete record

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-login, flask-admin

I make a tuition payment app using **Flask** and using **Flask-admin** to managing the payment. There is three **role** in this app which is **superuser**, **school admin** and the **parent** who want to see their children tuition.

I know how to make the **role** for the **superuser** and the **school admin**, which is the **superuser** can create the **school admin**, and the **school admin** can add and edit or delete a student data.

so far, this my code for the **school admin** modelview:

```
class SchoolAdminModelView(sqla.ModelView):
    def is_accessible(self):
        if not current_user.is_active or not current_user.is_authenticated:
            return False
        if current_user.has_role('schooladmin'):
            return True
        return False
    def _handle_view(self, name, **kwargs):
        if not self.is_accessible():
            if current_user.is_authenticated:
                abort(403)
            else:
                return redirect(url_for('security.login', next=request.url))
```

But for the **parent**, I want the parent account just can see or read data without access to modify it.

Like this image below:
[image]
That is the **school admin** view, now for the **parent** account I want to remove the edit and delete icon or the feature is.

So, how to do that..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the docs https://flask-admin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/mod_model/#flask.ext.admin.model.BaseModelView.can_create
You can add attributes to a model like edit, delete, create. Just bind this to a specific role where needed.

Comment: Thank you very much @gittert, you saved my time :)

Comment: of about if you are interested in changing the color of the edit and delete button, mine shows white for edit and black for delete i would like to change the delete to white also